# How to navigate the JSON hierarchy with PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am building a weather application that decodes a JSON file (found here: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Helsinki&appid=77f5e3fbc99649054660f82f871220f4&units=metric)

The problem I am running into is navigating the JSON file in my PHP code to correctly select the tempature.

I need to do `list->1->main->temp` but this pulls up a number error in PHP. How do I correctly set the navigation?

```
echo "<form id='searchform' method='POST' action='https://projekt2-sofiamusick.c9users.io/wordpress/prognos/'>
Search: <input type='text' name='searchquery' placeholder='Search the forum' />
<input class='sendbutton_search' type='submit' name='search' value='>>' />
</form>";

if (isset($_POST['search'])){

$cityz = $_POST['searchquery'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<div id=apithing>";
$data = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=$cityz&appid=77f5e3fbc99649054660f82f871220f4&units=metric");
$jsonObject = json_decode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
json_encode( array( 'list' => (int)$jsonObject ) );
$list = $jsonObject->list;
$number = $jsonObject->'1';
$mains = $jsonObject->main;
echo $mains;
```

Comment: try: `list[0]->main->temp` list will be an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`, your data present as array.
If you want get first element, just use `$jsonObject['list'][0]`

Without `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`, your data present as stdClass, and first element you can get with `$jsonObject->list{0}`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Helsinki&appid=77f5e3fbc99649054660f82f871220f4&units=metric");
$jsonObject = json_decode($data);
if($jsonObject->cod == '200' && count($jsonObject->list) > 0){
  foreach ($jsonObject->list as $jlk => $jlv) {
    $dt = $jlv->dt;
    $main = $jlv->main;
    // your rest of logic
  }
}
```

If you want you can see your data like this:

```
  echo '<pre>';
  var_dump($jsonObject);
  echo '</pre>';
  die;
```

Where you will see object, means you have to use "->" to access, and where you see array there use key of array to fetch that value.

Please feel free to ask, if any other doubt.